# is_dir just doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, installation

I'm try to develop a PHP MySQL website in which a is_dir function is required the existence of a "install" folder in the main folder, and then go the install folder (if the true) or continue the website (if false).

```
    if(is_dir("../install/"))
    {
            header("Location: ../install/");
    }
    else
    {
        require_once("config.php");
        $db=new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_);
        $db->query("SET NAMES utf8");
        global $db;
    }
```

But is_dir just doesn't detect the install folder. This file (named as core.php) is located at /scripts/ folder. Am I doing something wrong? '-'

Comment: Do you include core.php in another file that is located somewhere else? Are the folders *scripts* and *install* at the same level?

Comment: I discovered the problem! It was because core.php is a file that is called by a require_once in other pages. I was running the index.php which is exactly at /. But it's a trouble, cause I can't use absolute paths at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the current working directory for the process. Print it.

```
echo getcwd();
```

"install" should be a subdirectory in current working directory's parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

is_dir [documentation](https://www.php.net/is_dir):

```
If you have enabled safe mode, or open_basedir further restrictions may apply.
```

you could check if those restrictions are in effect in your server.

Answer (score 0):

`..` refers to the parent directory. e.g. if this particular script is running as `/foo/bar/script.php`, you're testing for `/foo/install/`.

Also note that header-based `Location` redirects are **URLs**. They do not always correspond to the actual file system in the server. If your script's url is `example.com/script.php`, then your is_dir test would be looking for a directory ABOVE the site's document root, which you could NOT redirect to.

```
 /home/sites/example.com/html/script.php -> example.com/script.php
 /home/sites/example.com/html/../install -> example.com/../install/
                         ^^^^^^^--these two collapse
                                                        ^^--can't go "up" from doc root
 /home/sites/example.com/install  -> example.com/install
```

and now the path mapping doesn't work anymore, because your URL path is "off" by one directory from the filesystem paths being used in PHP.